# How is Phong Shading implemented in GLSL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I am implementing a Phong Shader in GLSL for an assignment, but I don't get the same specular reflection as I should. The way I understood it, it's the same as Gouraud Shading, but instead of doing all the calculations in the vertex shader, you do them in the fragment shader, so that you interpolate the normals and then apply the phong model at each pixel. As part of the assignment I had to develop also the Gouraud shader and that works as supposed and I thought you just needed to put the vertex shader code into the fragment shader, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

What I do in the vertex shader is that I simply transform the vertex position into view coordinates and I apply the transpose inverse of the model view matrix to the vertex normal. Then, in the fragment shader I apply just the view transform to the light position and use these coordinates to calculate the vectors needed in the Phong model The lighting is almost correct, but some specular light is missing. All the parameters have been tested, so I would assume it's the light's position that is wrong, however I have no idea why my code wouldn't work when it does so in the other shader. Also, I know this isn't the most efficient way of doing it (pre-computing the normal matrix would be faster), I'm just trying to first get it to work properly.

Comment: Which of the matrices contains the View transformation? `MV` which I assume is Model-View or `PV` aka, Projection-View?

Comment: VMatrix is the View transform and as you said MV is the model-view while PV is the model-view-projection matrix

Comment: Then your problem is probably `normalize(mat3(VMatrix)*light)`. You effectively treat light as a direction here (ignore the camera position, only the orientation), but then use it as a position for the `L` calculation.

Comment: my reasoning was that I needed to convert the light coordinates into view coordinates in order to be able to find the L vector in the view space, but (I think) I understand what you're saying and I agree with you. However, removing the normalization doesn't change the scene at all. Also, from what I've learned, any point can be treated as a vector wrt its own coordinate system, so mixing between direction and points shouldn't be a problem as long as everything is normalized (and in the same coordinate system) since I only care about directions

Comment: The normalize is a problem, but also that you truncate the matrix to a mat3 (which removes the translation part). Try `vec3 l = (VMatrix * vec4(light, 1.0)).xyz`

Comment: that worked! thank you so much, I had already tried basically what you proposed but with vec4(light, 0.0) and that was very wrong apparently. you have saved me

Comment: Mathematically, vec4(light, 0.0) is a direction vector while vec4(light, 1.0) is a position vector. Practically, the w-coordinate is in the result multiplied with the translation part of the matrix. If you set it to 0, the translation is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way how the light source position is calculated. The following code

```
vec3 l = normalize(mat3(VMatrix)*light);
```

treats light as a direction (by normalizing it and because the translation part of the view matrix is ignored), but it actually is a position. The correct code should be something like

```
vec3 l = (VMatrix * vec4(light, 1.0)).xyz
```